# Как сохранить рабочий стол пользователя(набор открытых форм и их настроек)?

Tags: delphi, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем доброго дня. У меня вопрос по выбору метода для реализации. Имеется простое приложение которое позволяет выбрать базу данных и открывать потом таблицы из этой базы. Для открытия таблиц используется одна общая форма просто создается для каждой таблицы. Эти формы с таблицами технологией docking размещаются на гавной форме приложения. Задача состоит в том чтобы в контекстное меню главной формы добавить команды "сохранить рабочий стол" и "загрузить рабочий стол" которые соответственно позволят сохранить расположение формочек и открытых в них таблиц и загрузить.

Слышал что-то про фабрики, что нужно загонять все это хозяйство в одну фабрику и потом как то это все сериализовать. Подскажите кто значет как лучше это реализовать. Проблема сохранения рабочего стола довольно распростаненная кто-то наверное да сталкивался.

Мне пока в голуву приходит только создавать XML или просто файл со значениями количества форм, размеров и расположений а также назначенных им таблиц. Но проблема в том что у таблиц еще нужно настраивать отображаемые поля, поля сортировки и все это выльется в большую кучу кода. Вериться что есть более простой путь и можно просто застримить в файл все это дело и потом востановить.

Answer (score 1):

Если сериализовать, то ничего лучше XML и JSON пока не видел.

> Вериться что есть более простой путь и можно просто застримить в файл все это дело и потом восстановить.

Можно и так, но получите потом уйму непонятных багов которые нельзя отладить. Взял и по-портился файл вопреки всем законам вселенной, в итоге юзер потерял целый рабочий сеанс и угробил время все восстанавливая.

Так что, лучше вы руками пропишите кучу кода, с возможностью отладки и возможностью избежать конфликтов между разными форматами и структурой, нежели бинарного кота в мешке.